# Use aggregate function with arithmetic operation

Tags: sql, function, aggregate, operation

I have a table with two columns

[image]

Here I need to find a SQL according to the following function,

```
Z = accelx-AVG(accelx) for every rows.
```

Comment: and what database engine and version are you using?. What code have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

This is usually done with the analytic version of `AVG`:

```
select accelx - avg(accelx) over ()
from mytable;
```

Comment: You are right, but not all db has it . I would include `partition by  userName`

Comment: I would too, if I wanted the average per user. I don't if that is what the OP wants, however ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Simply calculate `AVG` in subquery:

```
SELECT AccelX - (SELECT AVG(AccelX) FROM T)
FROM T
```

Comment: Use a windowed function.  `AVG(AccelX) OVER ()`

Comment: @MatthewWhited Not every db has it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select t1.accelx - t2.avgx as Z
from TableName as t1
inner join (
    select avg(accelx) as avgx
    from TableName
    ) as t2
on 1 = 1
```

Comment: `on 1 = 1`? That's a cross join, so you should replace `inner join` with `cross join` and remove the dummy `on` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.accelx - t2.avgx as Z, userName 
FROM TableName as t1
JOIN (SELECT userName, avg(accelx) as avgx
      FROM TableName
      GROUP BY userName) as t2       
  ON t1.userName = t2.userName
```

Answer (score 0):

TSQL on MSSQL Server has Windowed functions.  [OVER Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

```
SELECT 
    [AccelX]
    ,[AccelX] - AVG([AccelX]) OVER ()
FROM T
```